# how to send a nested object as parameter?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have a json object to send. How should i send it as a post request in swift. Using alamofire or native http post i don't mind.

My object is like below:

```
{  
   "StartAddress":"Colombo",
   "EndAddress":"Kandy",
   "DepartureAddress":"Kollupitiya, Colombo",
   "ArrivalAddress":"Peradeniya, Kandy",
   "CreatedDate":"2017-07-30",
   "Date":"2017-07-30",
   "Time":"2017-07-30",
   "IsLadiesOnly":true,
   "IpAddress":"fe80::8638:38ff:fec8:ea50%wlan0",
   "Country":"Srilanka",
   "VehicleId":"1129",
   "StartLocation":[  
      6.9270974,
      79.8607731
   ],
   "EndLocation":[  
      7.2916216,
      80.6341326
   ],
   "Points":"k}gi@y{lf",
   "Route":{  
      "Bounds":{  
         "NorthEast":[  
            7.2916216,
            80.6341326
         ],
         "SouthWest":[  
            6.9270974,
            79.8607731
         ]
      },
      "Legs":[  
         {  
            "LegId":1,
            "Distance":14904,
            "Duration":1941,
            "StartAddress":"Colombo",
            "EndAddress":"Kadawatha",
            "StartLocation":[  
               6.9270974,
               79.8612478
            ],
            "EndLocation":[  
               7.0011125,
               79.95000750000001
            ],
            "Ancestors":[  

            ],
            "Price":745
         },
         {  
            "LegId":2,
            "Distance":63040,
            "Duration":6209,
            "StartAddress":"Kadawatha",
            "EndAddress":"Kegalle",
            "StartLocation":[  
               7.0011125,
               79.95000750000001
            ],
            "EndLocation":[  
               7.251436200000001,
               80.3466076
            ],
            "Ancestors":[  
               "Colombo"
            ],
            "Price":3152
         },
         {  
            "LegId":3,
            "Distance":38990,
            "Duration":4430,
            "StartAddress":"Kegalle",
            "EndAddress":"Kandy",
            "StartLocation":[  
               7.251436200000001,
               80.3466076
            ],
            "EndLocation":[  
               7.2901864,
               80.6338425
            ],
            "Ancestors":[  
               "Colombo",
               "Kadawatha"
            ],
            "Price":1950
         }
      ]
   },
   "TotalPrice":"5847.0",
   "SeatCount":1,
   "Detour":1,
   "Luggage":2,
   "DetoursDescription":"10 Minutes",
   "LuggageDescription":"Small Luggage",
   "Notes":"new ride"
}
```

I have tried with alamofire also but for that i have to convert this to a dictionary.
I want to send this object as body parameters , how can i do this?

Comment: You want to send json object am I right? For that you have to create json string first. then send in a single param

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the following:

```
let parameters: [String: AnyObject] = [
"IdQuiz" : 102,
"IdUser" : "iosclient",
"User" : "iosclient",
"List": [
    [
        "IdQuestion" : 5,
        "IdProposition": 2,
        "Time" : 32
    ],
    [
        "IdQuestion" : 4,
        "IdProposition": 3,
        "Time" : 9
    ]
]
]

 var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")




request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

Alamofire.request(request)
.responseJSON { response in
    // do whatever you want here
    switch response.result {
    case .failure(let error):
        print(error)

        if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print(responseString)
        }
    case .success(let responseObject):
        print(responseObject)
    }
}
```

Comment: you're using an old Alamofire version

Comment: @zombie check now

Comment: What if I want to send the parameters in the URL instead of body?

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code for the above json object:

```
do {
        let arrayStartLocation = [7.2916216, 80.6341326]
        let arrayEndLocation = [7.2916216, 80.6341326]
        let arrayNorthEast = [7.2916216, 80.6341326]
        let arraySouthWest = [7.2916216, 80.6341326]
        let dictBounds = ["NorthEast" : arrayNorthEast , "SouthWest": arraySouthWest]
        let dictRoute = ["Bounds" : dictBounds]
        let dictMain: [String : Any] = ["StartAddress": "Colombo",
                        "EndAddress": "Kandy",
                        "DepartureAddress": "Kollupitiya, Colombo",
                        "StartLocation": arrayStartLocation,
                        "EndLocation": arrayEndLocation,
                        "Route": dictRoute

        ///Similarly For remaining keys
        //    .......
        ]


        //Convert to Data
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictMain, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

        //Convert back to string. Usually only do this for debugging

        if let JSONString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            print(JSONString)/// Send this string in almofire

            Alamofire.request(AppUrl.CALL_ADD_REVIEWS, method: .post , parameters: ["yourPramName": JSONString]).responseJSON(completionHandler: { (response) in
                //Code here
            })
        }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
```